# How to target WooCommerce product loops inside a function

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

**loop/price.php**

I tried this and works, but not sure is it good way or not

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <?php add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'test_loop_price', 10, 3 );
    ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad idea as this is not the correct way to do it… Apparently, you are using a custom function named `test_loop_price()` and you didn't provide the code of that function in your question.

First remove your custom code from `loop/price.php` template file.

Then, you need to target WooCommerce product loop, inside that function like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'test_loop_price', 10, 3 );
function test_loop_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop, $product;

    if ( ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) ) {
        return $price;
    }

    ## Here below comes your existing code ##

    
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.